# style different sections of a page area on a single page with css

Tags: html, css, background, styles

How does one style the background color for a different section on a single page website? like this http://www.pinterest.com/pin/553802085401395433/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an element in the page
2. Write a selector to match it
3. Set the `background-color` property to whatever value you like
4. Add other styles or elements so that it doesn't cover the entire page